# material-table How to do selectable and editable table?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, material-table

i want to do this one(some actions for selected and some actions for each row). Help please, thanks!

[image]

I use `material-table` with `ReactJS`. Now I have actions on each row without selectable, if add selection prop these actions disappear. I don't know how to combine each row actions with multiple actions..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's [the exact place](https://github.com/mbrn/material-table/blob/master/src/components/m-table-body-row.js#L193) in the source where it is decided whether to show actions column when `selection` property is set to *true*:

```
if (this.props.actions && this.props.actions.filter(a => !a.isFreeAction && !this.props.options.selection).length > 0) {
    // ... 
}
```

Another such place is in `renderActions` [method](https://github.com/mbrn/material-table/blob/master/src/components/m-table-body-row.js#L37):

```
const actions = this.props.actions.filter(a => !a.isFreeAction && !this.props.options.selection);
```

So it either has to be a `isFreeAction` or `selection` should be set to *false*. The only way you can customize this at the moment is to override a `Row` component - basically copy/paste it, modify those conditions, import the result as a new component and supply it in `components` property of the `material-table` config as an override for `Row`.

CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-architecture-ggnrl

Answer (score 14):

You can add the `position: 'row'` prop to actions. There are 4 options available for the `position` prop: `auto`', `toolbar`, `toolbarOnSelect`, `row`

This minimal code snippet should work

```js
   <MaterialTable
          actions={[
            {
              icon: 'save',
              tooltip: 'Save User',
              position: 'row',
              onClick: (event, rowData) => alert('You saved ' + rowData.name)
            },
            {
              icon: 'delete',
              tooltip: 'Delete User',
              position: 'row',
              onClick: (event, rowData) =>
                alert('You want to delete ' + rowData.name)
            }
          ]}
          columns={[
            { title: 'Name', field: 'name' },
            { title: 'Surname', field: 'surname' },
            { title: 'Birth Year', field: 'birthYear', type: 'numeric' },
            {
              title: 'Birth Place',
              field: 'birthCity',
              lookup: { 34: 'İstanbul', 63: 'Şanlıurfa' }
            }
          ]}
          data={[
            {
              name: 'Mehmet',
              surname: 'Baran',
              birthYear: 1987,
              birthCity: 63
            },
            {
              name: 'Zerya Betül',
              surname: 'Baran',
              birthYear: 2017,
              birthCity: 34
            }
          ]}
          options={{
            selection: true,
            actionsColumnIndex: -1
          }}
          title="Positioning Actions Column Preview"
        />
```

Comment: This works! It is not in the documentation on material-table's website, but it definitely works.

Comment: This also worked for me, I think this should be the selected answer @oHorbachov

Comment: It's not working in case of using action as function e.g (rowData) => ({ position: "row", onClick: ...  })  !

Comment: In case anyone else can't get a good icon to show up, you use e.g. icon:Save and be sure to import {Save} from "@material-ui/icons"